# Assigning pods to nodegroups

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

Is there a way to assign pods to the nodes in a particular nodegroup without labeling each node in the nodegroup?

E.g.:

Suppose I have two nodegroup `NG1` and `NG2`, and I have two apps `A1` and `A2`

I want to assign pods of app `A1` to nodegroup `NG1` and pods of app `A2` to nodegroup `A2`. (I don't want to assign labels to each node in the nodegroup manually and then use nodeselector)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use some of the default labels if those are coming and not same across the both Node pools

```
failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone
failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/region
beta.kubernetes.io/instance-type
beta.kubernetes.io/os
beta.kubernetes.io/arch
```

For example, if both of your Node pool running the different type of instances, you can use the `beta.kubernetes.io/instance-type`

**Example**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: with-node-affinity
spec:
  affinity:
    nodeAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
        nodeSelectorTerms:
        - matchExpressions:
          - key: beta.kubernetes.io/instance-type
            operator: In
            values:
            - Node Type
            - Node Type
  containers:
  - name: with-node-affinity
    image: registry.k8s.io/pause:2.0
```

You can also use the `topology.kubernetes.io/zone` if zone if difference is there.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: with-node-affinity
spec:
  affinity:
    nodeAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
        nodeSelectorTerms:
        - matchExpressions:
          - key: topology.kubernetes.io/zone
            operator: In
            values:
            - antarctica-east1
            - antarctica-west1
  containers:
  - name: with-node-affinity
    image: registry.k8s.io/pause:2.0
```

**Update**

If all the labels are the **same** you can try below command, which will list and label from a specific node group `alpha.eksctl.io/nodegroup-name=ng-1` :

```
kubectl label nodes -l alpha.eksctl.io/nodegroup-name=ng-1 new-label=foo
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply harsh. But most of the default labels will be same. I am thinking of assigning one nodegroup for each app. The instances and other things in the nodegroup will be same for each one.

Comment: try this command once : `kubectl label nodes -l alpha.eksctl.io/nodegroup-name=ng-1 new-label=foo
`